# GLSL: will assignment from an uniform to never modified variable cause copying?

Tags: performance, opengl, glsl, shader

I am optimizing `glUniform` calls count. In some shader I have lots of vec2 uniform variables.

Initially their declarations looked like

```c
uniform vec2 foo;
uniform vec2 bar;
...
```

After optimizing I declared the following:

```c
uniform vec2 v2params[42];
vec2 foo = v2params[0];
vec2 bar = v2params[0];
...
```

GLSL 130 does not allow to qualify `foo, bar, ...` as `const` in this case, but they are never modified in further code.

Will modern GLSL compilers guess their constness and eliminate copying? Or should I use values like `v2params[0]` instead of `foo` to ensure absence of copying? The latter will significantly decrease code readability.

PS. I'm restricted to OpenGL 2 and WebGL 1, so UBOs are not available.

Comment: Isn't a variable with a `uniform` classifier automatically considered a constant (asking out of curiosity)? And what about [Uniform Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object)? Have You tried to use them? Or are You working on a GL version that does not support tehm?

Comment: @Matso You're right, UBOs are not supported in targeted OpenGL versions (added this to the question). Yes, uniforms are constant, but `foo` and `bar` in my example are mutable, and compiler cannot assume their constness a priori.